# Stop sound with button event

Tags: java, button, audio

I have code for sound that loops and plays on my GUI contained in the main class. 
Main class code:

```
public class SoundTest {
public static Clip clip;
public static Mixer mixer;
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    StartGUI GUI = new StartGUI();
    GUI.setVisible(true);

     Mixer.Info[] mixInfos = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
     mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixInfos[0]);

    DataLine.Info dataInfo = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, null);
    try{
        clip = (Clip)mixer.getLine(dataInfo);
    }
    catch(LineUnavailableException l){
        l.printStackTrace();

    }

    try{
        URL soundURL = Main.class.getResource("/soundtest/8-Bit-Noise-1.wav");
        AudioInputStream audioStrim = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundURL);
        clip.open(audioStrim);
    }
    catch(LineUnavailableException l){
        l.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(UnsupportedAudioFileException e ){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException i){
        i.printStackTrace();
    }
    clip.start();
    do{
        System.out.println(clip.isActive());
        try{
            clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
            Thread.sleep(50);

        }
        catch(InterruptedException ie){
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }while(clip.isActive());


}

public void stop() {
    clip.stop();
}
```

}

In my JFrame class I want to make a button event that will stop the sound, I have tried to make a stop() method in the main class to use it in the button but so far it is not working.

JFrame code:

```
public class StartGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    SoundTest q; 

    /**
     * Creates new form SoundTestGUI
     */
    public StartGUI() {
        initComponents();
    }



    private void SoundBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        q.stop();
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {


        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new StartGUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }     
}
```

Comment: How is it not working? Any exceptions being thrown?

Comment: I am assuming that SoundTest runs fine on its own. I am assuming that when you wrote StartGUI, your intention is to start the program with the main() method in StartGUI instead of SoundTest. Does the sound play when you do this? Part of the difficulty in helping is also that we don't see the code for button or how you attach the Listener to the Button. Also, the code that starts SoundTest should should probably be in the constructor, or in its own method, not the main method. That would help with clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to try calling SoundTest to play in the constructor. Stop the clip in the event button and try to check to see that your listeners are properly registered to listen to the event. You can use actionPerformed() to manage the events instead of using adapter on the button. There's no real advantage to this for me, it's just an alternative.